# "He ought to love her forever" or "He oughts to love her forever"

Tags: modal-verbs, subject-verb-agreement

Can anyone explain to me? But I found that most of the sentences use 'he ought'.

Answer (score 6):

"Ought" is a **modal verb** just like "can" or "should." Modal verbs are never conjugated. Use "ought" plus the infinitive of another verb.

I have to disagree with the other answer that it's almost dead. Here in Texas anyway, we use "ought to" (oughtta) fairly often.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to HiddenBabel's correct answer:

The *proper* use is always "ought".  Modal verbs are not conjugated:

> They **ought** to leave now if they want to catch the bus.
>
> I **ought** to stop watching TV and start studying for my exam

However, some English dialects do say "oughts" instead of "ought".  This usually would be written only in narrative dialogue.

> "You **oughts** not to 'ave done that," the thief warned, recovering from the ineffectual blow and raising his knife. "Now we're gonna do this the 'ard way."

It's specious to say that "ought" is not used in modern English, as it's still quite common.  That being said, it can be more emphatic than "should", so it's a little strange to say something like "He *ought* to love her forever". It sounds like a *command*, like

> He is **morally obligated** to love her forever

or a *threat*:

> He will **suffer dire consequences** if he does not love her forever

or (as Michael Harvey suggests) *uncertainty*:

> It should be true that he will love her forever, but I'm not sure.

rather than an *ideal* or a *prediction*

> He looks so happy, I **expect** that he will love her forever.

Comment: Andrew - ""He _ought_ to love her forever" - said with an emphasis on 'ought' would express a certain kind of uncertainty or tentativeness - he should, really, love her forever, but, well, we know what people can be like, etc. The repair I have just made to the shed ought to last a while (but might not).

Answer (score 0):

Ought there is a **modal verb** like 'can', 'could', 'will', 'would', etc.
You don't say "he **cans** do that" but instead you say "he **can** do that"
Hence, "*he ought to love her forever*" is correct.

Answer (score -4):

The word "ought" is an old word, and usage has been steadily falling to very low levels.  I would suggest that you don't use it. In modern English, "ought to" has been almost completely replaced by "should". There are a few specific phrases that still sometimes use "ought", but in general modern speakers will just hear "ought" as a strange-sounding way to say "should".

The best answer to your question is:
*He should love her forever*

If you insist on saying "ought":
*He ought to love her forever*

Few English speakers will know this, but the formal meaning of "ought" is a little bit stronger than "should". "Ought" suggests a duty, obligation, or debt.

The word "oughts" is **completely dead** in modern English. Google can't find even one use of "oughts" in a real sentence. "Oughts" would only be used when referring to more than one duty, obligation, and/or debt at the same time.

Comment: Modern speakers where? In Britain, "I ought to be going now" and "I should be going now" are equally valid, and "ought" has definitely **not** vanished, died, or acquired an obsolete status.

Comment: "Ought" may be declining, but it's far from dead.

Comment: A youtube English lessons video gives the same advice for English learners not to use ought, and the Google ngram viewer shows the low-and-declining usage of ought. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vAsEG6A0Jj0  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ought%2Cshould&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15

Comment: Your ngram link shows that "should" is also declining. But that doesn't mean in speech we don't use the word "should" anymore. You can't read the ngram viewer that straightforwardly. As for that video, I'm not sure. Maybe some parts of America have lost it...